# Launch multiple instances of Java with one jar

Tags: java, jar, multiple-instances

Is it possible to launch multiple instances of a jar file without making copies of the file and running each one individually?

For example I have two simultaneous instances that use the exact same Jar file.
They are located in different places and both use a large amount of Processing power to run.

Since I run both of these at startup and they both use the same Jar file just duplicates of it in this case.

Is there a way to drop one of the copies and have both instances run from the same jar file without suffering from performance loss or potentially increasing load times if they both use the same class files inside the file at the same time?

Comment: It's probably not so good thoughts... you want to start from preventing of launch multiple instances , but before, you need to somehow register instances inside of your service started the first. Have a look at this post. Other info i hope you will find in the internets. http://www.daniweb.com/software-development/java/threads/83331/how-to-stop-opening-multiple-instance-for-a-jar-file

Comment: it seems like you want to add client-server logic into your program.

Comment: Despite all the odd comments above, and your rather creative concerns, there's absolutely nothing wrong with doing this. In fact it's done all the time. Just launch the app as many times as you need to and don't worry about it.

Comment: but will it require more processing power? that is one of my main concerns about this as well

Comment: If you do twice as much work it will require twice the computing power. If you do the same amount of work divided between two copies, it will take roughly the same amount of power.

Comment: @FateAverie why odd? It's better think about normal application architecture. Well, maybe i'm kinda silly and don't understand something...

Answer (score 0):

It's not the JAR that's an "instance" - it's the java process that executes what's in the JAR.

Have you tried just launching it twice under separate processes? What were the results and if it didn't work why didn't it work?

Comment: I'm sure it would launch, although I haven't tried, I don't want to accidentally break something on the system as I'm not the best Linux User, and seeing as I am in a terminal view only I wouldn't be able to see any differences unless I watch my top or htop, the problem with that is that the Java Process fluctuates anyway so unless I watch it for an hour at least on both tries and hope that they run the same process on both instances I wouldn't be able to accurately tell if it makes a difference or not, which is why I'm looking for answers here before I try anything....

Comment: Does the JAR/application modify data? In other words, why do you think there are two copies of it now? Is it to make sure the two copies don't modify the same data, say, in the same folder? What exactly does this JAR of yours do? What kind of application is it?

Answer (score 0):

In linux, put an `&` after the first java command

```
java -jar thejarfile.jar com.main.class.file & 
java -jar thejarfile.jar com.main.class.anotherfile
```